# Visual studio 2019 - C++ console application. Files to ship with exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I currently have a cpp console application developed  using Visual Studio 2019.
I would now like to run this exe onto other machines by pasting it there. I dont want to create an installer. My question is if there is any resource online that would tell me what system files need to be shipped with the exe.

Comment: Just the `.exe` if you linked the runtimes statically and don't use any 3rd party libraries, Otherwise you'll need to ship the runtime DLLs, which exactly depends on whether you are also using the standard C++ library or MFC, and whether you can assume that the target versions of Windows have the UCRT installed or not. See [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160) and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a standalone exe that "just works" on the target machine without any special installer, just make sure you link to the C/C++ runtime statically.  That's pretty much all you have to do.

In Visual Studio, in the project settings window, select C/C++ -> Code Generation and select "Multithreaded" instead of "Multithreaded DLL" for the Runtime Library option.

The result is a bigger EXE file, but all the dependencies for C/C++ libraries are linked directly into it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Ill try this and post back

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is resolved, could you mark them as answer? Because this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Seems like this results in a bunch of linker errors in my case. I am trying to figure out what those errors are

Answer (score 0):

The `dumpbin.exe` that comes with VS can view the dlls that the .exe depends on. The `Microsoft COFF Binary File Dumper (DUMPBIN.EXE)` displays information about Common Object File Format (COFF) binary files. You can use `DUMPBIN` to examine COFF object files, standard libraries of COFF objects, executable files, and dynamic-link libraries (DLLs).

To run DUMPBIN, use the following syntax:

```
DUMPBIN [options] files...
```

Check dependencies:

For example: `dumpbin /dependents test.exe`

Also, you could refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160) for more information.